# Meteor: IronRouter does not trigger notFound rule

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I would like my Meteor app to use [IronRouter](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-iron-router) for client-side routing.

My routing code looks as follows:

```
Router.map(function() { 
    this.route('story', {
        path: '/story/:_id',
        data: function() {
            return Stories.findOne({displayId: +this.params._id}); 
        },
        notFound: 'storyNotFound'
    });
});
```

I have 2 templates corresponding to this route:

```
<template name="story">
    Welcome to story: {{this.displayId}}.
</template>

<template name="storyNotFound">
    Story not found
</template>
```

**Problem**: the 'storyNotFound' template is *never* rendered, not even when

```
Stories.findOne({displayId: +this.params._id})
```

returns undefined.

Instead, the 'story' template is rendered with the text "Welcome to story: ".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried replacing `notFound:` with `notFoundTemplate` ? The Iron Router example uses `notFound` but I could only find `notFoundTemplate` in the source code and that worked for me.

```
Router.map(function() { 
    this.route('story', {
        path: '/story/:_id',
        data: function() {
            return Stories.findOne({displayId: +this.params._id}); 
        },
        notFoundTemplate: 'storyNotFound'
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the confusion. I'm cleaning a lot of this up in the dev branch. Generally, anything that applies to templates has 'Templates' at the end of the option. notFoundTemplate, layoutTemplate, yieldTemplates, template.